# Display events in a grid with Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase analytics to receive some analytics about a game.

I added an Event that gets information when a user finishes a level.
Like Level number, Stars collected, total time in the level and Retry Times.

Firebase displays it in the following way:

[image]

Is there a way to display the data more efficiently like with a grid using Firebase?

rough example:

```
Level 1 - Total users [106], avg total time [70] seconds, avg stars [2.5]
Level 2 - Total users [80], avg total time [65] seconds, avg stars [2.2] 
Level 3 - Total users [56], avg total time [55] seconds, avg stars [2.7]
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console display can't be customized.  If you want to customize the display of data collected by Google Analytics, you will have to [export the data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7030014?hl=en), and you can do whatever you want with it from there.

Comment: Would i be able to query firebase analytics events with BigQuery without adding my credit card?

Comment: No, BigQuery requires a payment plan.

Comment: @Dror Note that you can use BigQuery Sandbox for free with [pretty generous limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limits). It does not require a credit card.